# Is there a method in dojo 1.6 to get the current page for dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid?

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

My first question, please be kind.

I'm using the Enhanced Grid's pagination plugin and I cannot find how to get the handle on the current page.

For example:

I am on page 3 of 10 pages, i want to store this page number in my cookie so that when I return to the grid it will automatically scroll to the page and highlight the row.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide what code you have tried.

Comment: I have not tried the code because I cant find the handle on the current page.  Looking at the documentation I see only - gotoPage(),nextPage(),gotoFirstPage(),changePageSize() but nothing to get me the current page.  Thanks.

Comment: I figured out how to work around this,  query the data store and use that return to determine what page to scroll to.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will give you the current page of grid.

```
grid.plugin('pagination')._currentPage
```